# Скролинг за курсором мышки Datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, прокрутка, datagridview

Сделал внутри datagridview drag drop, появилась проблема, например : нужно перетащить последнею строку на первое место, при этом первое место под скролом, как сделать что бы когда курсор мыши приблизился к верхней\нижней части datagridview, скролинг начался автоматом в верх или вниз в зависимости от направления перетаскивания элемента?

Comment: Можно попробовать так:
использовать `DataGridView.CellMouseEnter` - возникает при наведении указателя мыши на ячейку. Мы знаем сколько строк  вмещается в видимую часть таблицы. В момент перетаскивания строки мы будем знать и то, над какой ячейкой мы сейчас находимся. Если в данный момент мышь нажата, а индекс строки выбранной и наведенной имеют разницу равную количеству отображаемых строк минус один - менять свойство `dataGridView.CurrentCell`, в зависимости от того, получили положительное или отрицательное число - меняем в большую или меньшую сторону.

Comment: Или с использованием `dataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` вместо `dataGridView.CurrentCell` реализовать данный функционал

Comment: @DenisBubnov пробовал с `dataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex`, вешал его на `Mouse Move` , Делал так если индекс того что под мышкой и `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` равны друг другу то `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` +1. Но оно как то то работает то не работает то индекс сроки на которой мышка неправильно считает =(. Попробую с `CurrentCell`.

Comment: там просто нужно реализовать правильную логику, чтобы и за пределы диапазона не уйти, и в определенный момент вычитать единицу, а не прибавлять. Продолжайте использовать `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex`

Comment: *Делал так если индекс того что под мышкой и FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex равны друг другу то FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex +1* - это правильно. А второй случай - это когда (FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex + **количество видимых строк**) = (индекс того что под мышкой) - в этом случае FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex - 1